# Uncaught TypeError: t is undefined while trying to load json via ThreeJS ObjectLoader

Tags: javascript, node.js, three.js

I'm trying to parse an object in JSON format from server-side using `THREE.ObjectLoader()` but browser throws a following error: `Uncaught TypeError: t is undefined`.

Here's the file on the client-side
`initRender.js`

```
socket.on('sendBackMeshData', (meshData) => {
    let geometry = meshData[0],
        material = meshData[1];

    let loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
        model = loader.parse(geometry);

        const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(model, material);

        scene.add(mesh);

        render();
});
```

Here's the server-side file `triangulation.js`

```
let newIO = (io) => {
    io.sockets.on('connection', (socket) => {
        socket.on('send3dModelInfo', (data) => {
            let triangles = earcut(vertices, null, 3);

            const geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
                  geometry.addAttribute('position', new Float32Array(triangles), 3);
                  geometry.toJSON();
            const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                color: 0xff0000,
                wireframe: true
            });

            let meshData = [];
                meshData.push(geometry, material);

            socket.emit('sendBackMeshData', meshData);
        });
    });
}
```

What could be a problem? I saw on others similar questions that I should to include `ObjectLoader` loader via `<script>` tag. I tried it but it doesn't work either.

UPDATE:

`geometry.toJSON()` output:

```
{
  uuid: '51332EF3-B9B3-421E-89CF-6478FD480866',
  name: '',
  type: 'BufferGeometry',
  index: null,
  attributes: {
    position: {
      uuid: 'AEFF3E9F-2903-4DD9-A018-4A0420E43539',
      array: [Float32Array],
      itemSize: 3,
      dynamic: false,
      updateRange: [Object],
      version: 0,
      normalized: false
    }
  },
  morphAttributes: {},
  groups: [],
  boundingBox: null,
  boundingSphere: null,
  drawRange: { start: 0, count: Infinity }
}
```

Comment: Could we get more info on the error? Where exactly does the error occur? It would be very useful to know *where* the `undefined` variable is taking place. Also, what's the output of `geometry.toJSON()`?

Comment: @Marquizzo, this error occurs at `three.min.js:2:519579` when line `model = loader.parse(geometry);` is executed.
I added `geometry.toJSON()` output to the update section of my question post.

Comment: you could use the un-minified version of three.js to see the code around the error.